# Insert From URL script step returns error 1631 FileMaker 13

Tags: filemaker

I am getting error 1631 (The connection failed) when executing the Insert From URL script step using a path to a local file.

What is the correct path to use?  I have tried the following:

```
filemac://Macintosh SSD/Users/darrenburgess/Desktop/fileName.pdf
file:///Macintosh SSD/Users/darrenburgess/Desktop/fileName.pdf
file:/Macintosh SSD/Users/darrenburgess/Desktop/fileName.pdf
```

Does anyone know the correct path?
Do I need to escape the spaces?

Comment: Ok, I figured this out.  The correct path, at least on mac os, would be something like this:

    file://Macintosh SSD/Users/darrenburgess/Desktop/fileName.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct path to the desktop on mac. presumably this would work with the temporary path as well.

```
file:///Volumes/Macintosh SSD/Users/user/Desktop/filename.pdf
```

but this also works, contrary to the linked documentation:

file://Macintosh SSD/Users/user/Desktop/filename.pdf

FileMaker discusses the issue here:
http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/12505/related/1